# Preenchimento condicional de cor de fundo da linha do Django admin

Tags: javascript, python, django

Estou querendo coloris uma linha inteira de uma tabela, se a respectiva coluna dessa linha tiver algum texto, há tres situações possiveis:
1. o texto em si, 2. campos com um "-", 3. campos sem nada. A coluna referente é a 9, campo observação, e tentei da seguinte forma , sem exito:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#result_list tr:nth-child(9)').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() != '-') {
  $(this).css({
      "background-color": 'yellow',
      "color" : "black"
  });
}
if ($(this).text() != '') {
 $(this).css({
     "background-color": 'yellow',
      "color" : "black"
  });
}

});
});
})(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai o que acabei de testar no admin do Django 2.0.x a partir do console do Chrome.

Antes, para toda coluna de um campo, Django adiciona uma classe no formato `field-nomedocampo`. Isso deve renderizar no html:

`<td class="field-campo">texto</td>`

Então, diante disso, acredito que seu jquery pode ser algo como:

```
var $ = django.jQuery; // precisei disso para testar a solução
$('#result_list .field-SEU_CAMPO_AQUI').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "-") {
        $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
```

Espero que seja útil.